# R: How to apply a substring to a nested list?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am looking to substring a nested list inside a tibble, specifically limiting the number of characters in the list. In my case here is the object of interest:

```
my_list <- list(
  a =
    tibble(
      code = c("ax","yz"),
      affected_rows =
        c(list(1:10),list(200))
    ),
  b = 
    tibble(
      workid = c("123","456"),
      sheet = c("sheet1", "sheet2")
    )
)
```

I am looking to take the `affected_rows` column list and substring the first list with the numbers 1:10 so that it only has 4 characters. Not sure what's the best way to approach this when performing the operation on the entire list.

Output expected:
I am expecting to change the output of this (so the nchar of the list is brought down to 4):

```
my_list[1]$a$affected_rows[1]

    [[1]]
     [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

to something like:
        [[1]]
         [1]  1  2
```

I've tried the following thus far with no success:

```
lapply(my_list, function(y)  {
  y %>% dplyr::mutate(across(where(is.list), ~ substring(.x,0,4)))
}
)
```

Comment: `substring` is useful for character strings.  The one you wanted  to subset is a vector of integers `str(my_list$a$affected_rows[[1]])
 int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: i.e. if you want to do this only when you have character or else get the head `map(my_list, ~ .x %>% mutate(across(where(is.list), ~  map(.x, ~ if(is.character(.x)) substring(.x, 1, 4) else head(.x, 2)))))`

Answer (score 0):

It is a vector of integers and not a string.  So, we may need a check to apply `substring`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(my_list, ~ 
   .x %>% 
   mutate(across(where(is.list),
    ~  map(.x, ~ if(is.character(.x)) substring(.x, 1, 4) else head(.x, 2)))))
```